# Mapping nested JSON with Java class using Gson

Tags: java, gson

The json is

```
{
    "a": "Y",
    "b": "Y",
    "c": "Y",
    "d": "Y",
    "someList": [
        {
            "id": "somevalue"
        },
         
        {
            "id": "somevalue"
        }
    ]
}
```

for that my java class model is

```
class Response
   String a,b,c,d;
   ArrayList<Id> idList;
   
  //along with getters and setters.
```

and below is the implementation of Id class

```
public class Id {
    private String id;

    public String getid() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setid(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Now i parse this as below in a servlet class.

```
Response details = new Gson().fromJson(request.getReader(),Response.class);
```

when i print all the string variables like a,b,c,d, it prints
but when i try to print the list like

```
System.out.println(details.getidList());
```

The result is something like Id@57eff207.ie. it prints the memory location.
Now is there any problem with my class structure?. why not able to map the arraylist?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps overriding `toString()` in `Id` helps? Something like

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return this.id;
}
```